# C# How to open pdf on a certain title

Tags: c#, pdf

I am currently using the `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` to open a PDF.

But I want the PDF to open on a certain page and on a certain heading with Adobe Acrobat.

Let's say I want to open PDF reports in application startup path and I want to focus on book reports on page 16.

How would I accomplish this? I can get it to open on a certain page but cannot get it to focus on a certain title or heading.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the application passing parameters to it.

[Here's the manual](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf)

This is how it's formatted:

```
<Acrobat path> /A "<parameter>=<value>" "<PDF path>"
```

You will also need to escape the quotes inside the command string.

This is the command you'd run to open your PDF on Adobe Acrobat on page 16:

```
Process.Start("Acrobat.exe /A \"page=16\" \"C:\path\to\your\file.pdf\"");
```

You said you want to open on a certain title or heading. In order to do that, these should be named destinations. Then you can use the `nameddest` argument.

Let's say you have a named destionation called `summary`, you'd open the PDF on Summary like this:

```
Process.Start("Acrobat.exe /A \"nameddest=summary\" \"C:\path\to\your\file.pdf\"");
```

Comment: Thank you very much